# A regex to remove all words which contains number in R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I want to write a regex in R to remove all words of a string containing numbers.

For example:

```
first_text = "a2c if3 clean 001mn10 string asw21"
second_text = "clean string
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you get errors post code and any error messages

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does R stand for?

Comment: R is a programming language that is primarily used for statistical computing and graphics. It is available for free. Users can compile and run R on various operating systems including Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

The language is known to be fairly unconventional compared to popular software development languages such as C++ or Java. What makes R stand out from most other languages is that it acts as an interactive statistical environment. [reference](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28800/r-programming-language)

Comment: @Phil I tried to remove some codes containing numbers from my text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with `gsub`

```
trimws(gsub("\\w*[0-9]+\\w*\\s*", "", first_text))
#[1] "clean string"
```

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to select words with no numbers than to select and delete words with numbers:

```
> library(stringr)
> str1 <- "a2c if3 clean 001mn10 string asw21"
> paste(unlist(str_extract_all(str1, "(\\b[^\\s\\d]+\\b)")), collapse = " ")
[1] "clean string"
```

Note:

- Backslashes have to be escaped in R to work properly, hence double backslashes
- \b is word boundary
- \s is white space
- \d is digit character
- a caret (^) inside square brackets is a negater: find characters that do not match ...
- "+" after the character group inside [] means "1 or more" occurrences of those (non white space and non digit) characters

Answer (score 3):

Just another alternative using `gsub`

```
trimws(gsub("[^\\s]*[0-9][^\\s]*", "", first_text, perl=T))
#[1] "clean  string"
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit longer than some of the answers but very tractable is to first convert the string to a vector of words, then check word by word if there are any numbers and use standard `R` subsetting.

```
first_text_vec <- strsplit(first_text, " ")[[1]]
first_text_vec
[1] "a2c"     "if3"     "clean"   "001mn10" "string"  "asw21"  
paste(first_text_vec[!grepl("[0-9]", first_text_vec)], collapse = " ")
[1] "clean string"
```